# Read hector quadrotor position and control its yaw angles

Tags: rostopic, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am running hector quadrotor demo with two spawn quadrotors and get two questions:

1. How to read quadrotor's position? I asked it to show topics "/uav/uav1/fix" and it was supposed to show (latitude,longitude, altitude). However, when I move the UAV, only altitude change with the moving. Latitude and longitude don't change. Thus, I don't know how to read position (x,y).
2. Cannot control its pitch angle and roll angle. I published "geometry_msgs/Twist" to "cmd_vel",and I can control its yaw angle. But whatever value I chosen for message to publish, pitch angle and roll angle don't change.

I appreciate any advice.

Thanks
Glen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186435/read-hector-quadrotor-position-and-control-its-yaw-angles/) by [Glen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19650/glen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2014-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZP](https://answers.ros.org/users/27036/zp/) on 2016-05-31**:
Have you solved the second question about the pitch angle and roll angle? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Position messages are PoseStamped kind of messages. You can subscribe to the /uav1/ground_truth_to_tf/pose topic to get quadrotor's position. Then you can display its axes values using a callback function.

void callback_u1(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& ps)
{
ROS_INFO_STREAM(ps.pose.position.x);
ROS_INFO_STREAM(ps.pose.position.y);
ROS_INFO_STREAM(ps.pose.position.z);
}

---

Originally posted by [Humberto Beltrao](https://answers.ros.org/users/20626/humberto-beltrao/) with karma: 30 on 2015-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AbdealiJK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22426/abdealijk/) on 2015-06-19**:
Any clue about sending data to control the quad ?

**Comment by [Humberto Beltrao](https://answers.ros.org/users/20626/humberto-beltrao/) on 2015-06-19**:
You can use the publisher-subscriber data exchanging for this purpose. Once you know the desired (x, y, z) point you want the quad to go you can:

1. Publish velocity commands to the quad using uav/cmd_vel;
2. Check the distance between quad's position and the desired point using subscriber policy

**Comment by [AbdealiJK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22426/abdealijk/) on 2015-06-19**:
Ah - awesome - thanks :)